# restoreGeometry() misbehaves for QMdiSubWindow

Tags: c++, qt, qmdiarea

The following program creates a QDialog as a subwindow in a MDI area.

I'm trying to use `saveGeometry()` and `restoreGeometry()` to keep the dialog at the same position and size as it was shown the previous time.

That mostly works but there is an annoying difference when the restored position is around the top of the MDI area. Meaning, it seems that `restoreGeometry()` *is avoiding that zone*.

If you run the program and select *test->open*, the dialog appears at (0,0). Then, if you immediately close it, and select *test->open* again, the dialog appears at (0,y), where y is (I suspect) *the height of the title bar*.

Every time you move the dialog near the top, it reincarnates a little below.

For other positions, the dialog is restored perfectly.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc,argv);
    QMainWindow  win;
    QMenu        *mnu;
    QAction      *act;
    QMdiArea     mdi;
    QByteArray   abt;
    mnu=win.menuBar()->addMenu("test");
    act=mnu->addAction("open");
    mnu->addAction(act);
    QObject::connect(
        act,
        &QAction::triggered,
        [&]() {
            if(!mdi.subWindowList().count()) {
                QDialog       dlg;
                QMdiSubWindow *sub=mdi.addSubWindow(&dlg);
                if(abt.isEmpty())
                    sub->resize(200,200);
                else
                    sub->restoreGeometry(abt);
                dlg.exec();
                abt=sub->saveGeometry();
            }
        }
    );
    win.setCentralWidget(&mdi);
    win.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Any ideas about this behavior? Thank you.

Comment: Uhm. I can't test your code, but, as far as I can remember, the save/restore geometry functions are intended for top level windows only (it may be a lack in the documentation too, btw): they don't work as expected for child widgets. A possible alternative, is to manually store the widget geometry within the MDI area within a QByteArray or the QSetting.

Comment: @musicamante I don't think saving the geometry is a problem. The real deal is in restoring it. From a QByteArray, that is.

Comment: No, saving the geometry is the *beginning* of the problem. If you closely look at the `saveGeometry()` implementation, you'll see that it also saves the screen number and its geometry in the byte array, along with the widget geometry, which is always in coordinates that are relative to the parent. Restoring then becomes a further problem, because of both the `storeGeometry()` and `saveGeometry()` implementations. Those functions are intended and considered only for top level windows (and the screens they're shown on). The MDI area has a quite different context and you *must* consider that.

Comment: If you want to save and restore the state and geometry of a MDI window, you *must* do it on your own serialization. You can do it with a basic QByteArray/QDataStream combination, or even by using QSettings. The storing mechanism is fundamentally irrelevant, the context is what matters, both in saving and in restoring, also considering possible event delays caused by window management (which are normally taken care with from the `restoreGeometry()` geometry, but you'll probably need to implement on your own for an MDI area).

Comment: @musicamante OK, thanks for the insights. I usually do this with QSettings, but found about save/restoreGeometry() by looking for something unrelated. Seemed quick and neat but ended being a total waste of time. :/

Comment: It's not a total waste of time: even failure is useful for experience :-)